# bash delete files whose filename contain asterisks

Tags: bash, filenames, delete-file

How can one in bash delete files whose filename contain asterisks? I mean, using wildcards. If I do

```
rm -fr *filter*
```

I will delete all files in which the word "filter" appears in the filename, but what when the files do contain asterisk?

EDIT: Following your advice, I am not able to delete this

```
*filter*xyz*.data
```

Comment: It would help if you told us which of those asterisks are literal and which are wild cards.

Comment: if `ls *filter*` shows you the file, then `rm *filter*` will delete it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`rm -rf \*filter\*` or `rm -rf '*filter*'`

Comment: You only need to "escape" the asterisks that are actual asterisks.  So if you want to delete all the files that contain `filter` followed by an asterisk followed by `xyz` followed by any other characters and ending with `.data`, you would do `rm -rf *filter\*xyz*.data`

Comment: ok, and now I realize this would be much easier; how do I get a list of all the files that just contain asterisks in their filenames? independently of the filter

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf '*filter*'
```

Should work well.  Use quotes (updated to single based on comment).

Comment: @Paul +1 I wasn't aware of the slight difference between single and double quotes.  For asterisks double is OK but for some other chars the special meaning is retained.  Thanks!  http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_8.html#SEC8